# PhoneGap iPhone Code Description

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have the following code in PhoneGap iPhone, in file Geofence.js

```
Geofence.prototype.subscribeToLayer = function(layerName,circularRadius,successCallback){
PhoneGap.exec("Geofence.subscribeToLayer",layerName, circularRadius,{
              onSuccess:GetFunctionName(successCallback),
              });
```

Here there

```
        Geofence.h
        Geofence.m
```

These are methods in 
            Geofence class

```
          -(void)subscribeToLayer:(NSArray *)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary *)options;
```

I want someone to describe these lines of code, I am an iOS Developer, but not strong concepts of jQuery Mobile, and JS.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's parts of a PhoneGap plugin implementation.

The first part with `PhoneGap.exec` defines a wrapper function to hide the implementation details of the platforms JavaScript PhoneGap "runtime".

The second part is the native iOS side of the plugin. `subscribeToLayer:withDict:` is the instance method that will be called when calling the JavaScript function. An instance of the `Geofence` class will be created when starting up PhoneGap.

There should also be a key/value pair in the `plugins` dictionary in the `PhoneGap.plist` file to inform PhoneGap about the plugin and how to map it to a Objective-C class.

But is this code quite old? I think the plugin API looks a bit different in newer versions, at least for iOS.